# selinux prevents nagios config from being accessed

Tags: nagios, selinux

I'm running nagios 4 under centos 7. And everything works fine with SELinux disabled. But when I enable it, I am getting this error in the interface:

```
Whoops!

Error: Could not open CGI config file '/etc/nagios/cgi.cfg' for reading!

Here are some things you should check in order to resolve this error:

Make sure you've installed a CGI config file in its proper location. See the error message about for details on where the CGI is expecting to find the configuration file. A sample CGI configuration file (named cgi.cfg) can be found in the sample-config/ subdirectory of the Nagios source code distribution.
Make sure the user your web server is running as has permission to read the CGI config file.
Make sure you read the documentation on installing and configuring Nagios thoroughly before continuing. If all else fails, try sending a message to one of the mailing lists. More information can be found at https://www.nagios.org.
```

I tried checking audit2why to see if I can get a clue on how to handle this:

And I'm seeing this output:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1444272414.200:15955): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=9090 comm="status.cgi" name="cgi.cfg" dev="xvda1" ino=19230613 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nagios_etc_t:s0 tclass=file

        Was caused by:
                Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.

    type=AVC msg=audit(1444272474.545:15956): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=9116 comm="status.cgi" name="cgi.cfg" dev="xvda1" ino=19230613 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:nagios_etc_t:s0 tclass=file

            Was caused by:
                    Missing type enforcement (TE) allow rule.

                    You can use audit2allow to generate a loadable module to allow this access.
```

And if I check audit2allow, this is what I'm seeing:

```
[root@monitor1:~] #grep nagios /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow


#============= httpd_sys_script_t ==============
allow httpd_sys_script_t nagios_etc_t:file { read getattr open };

#============= httpd_t ==============
allow httpd_t admin_home_t:file { write getattr open };
allow httpd_t etc_t:dir write;
allow httpd_t etc_t:file write;
allow httpd_t httpd_sys_rw_content_t:fifo_file getattr;
allow httpd_t usr_t:fifo_file { write getattr open };
```

But I'm not real knowledgable on SELinux. So I'm hoping I can get some advice on how to solve this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep` the `audit.log` for the word `nagios` and pipe it into `audit2allow` with the `-M` flag

```
grep nagios /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M nagios
```

This should create 2 files: a type enforcement file `nagios.te` and a policy package file `nagios.pp`

Use the `semodule` command to load the policy package:

```
semodule -i nagios.pp
```

And you're done.

Sources:

- https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/sec-sel-building-policy-module.html
- https://mgrepl.fedorapeople.org/Blog/nagios.html

Comment: Hey! Thanks! I gave that a try.
[root@monitor1:~] #grep nagios /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow  -M nagios
******************** IMPORTANT ***********************
To make this policy package active, execute:

semodule -i nagios.pp

But when I try to install the module I'm getting an error:
[root@monitor1:~] #semodule -i nagios.pp
libsepol.print_missing_requirements: nagios's global requirements were not met: type/attribute nagios_etc_t (No such file or directory).
libsemanage.semanage_link_sandbox: Link packages failed (No such file or directory).
semodule:  Failed!

Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you run `semodule -l` and see if `nagios` is already listed?  If so, change the name `nagios` that you pass to the `-M` flag to something else like `nagios1`

Comment: hey! that worked. I already had a module called nagios, so that's why that was happening.

[root@monitor1:~] #semodule -i nagios1.pp
[root@monitor1:~] #

Thanks!